# How can I call a public function from a Private Sub in VB.Net?

Tags: string, vb.net, listbox

I'm making an antivirus in vb.net and I have a button to scan the whole C:/ drive. I have a block of code to verify the files but I don't know how to call it from my button. I want the files to be listed in a ListBox.

**Scan:**

```
 Public Function GetFilesRecursively(path As String, searchPattern As String) As String()
    Dim filePaths As New List(Of String)(Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern))

    For Each folderPath In Directory.GetDirectories(path)
        Try
            filePaths.AddRange(GetFilesRecursively(folderPath, searchPattern))
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            'Ignore inaccessible folders
        End Try
    Next

    Return filePaths.ToArray()
End Function
```

**Button:**

```
Private Sub button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button9.Click
    GetFilesRecursively(Environment.SystemDirectory, ListBox1)
    ProgressBar1.Update()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

**Error I'm receiving:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   BC30311 Value of type 'ListBox' cannot be converted to 'String'.    Scorpion Defender PRO   D:\Scorpion Defender PRO\Scorpion Defender PRO\Form3.vb 52  Active

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim DirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\")
On Error Resume Next
For Each file In DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("*", searchOption:=IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Next
```

Comment: When using the .ToArray(), its refusing access. If I remove .ToArray(), it's just doing nothing. Can you help me a little bit more?

Comment: i updated the answer to match your new needs.

It will now skip files that it does not have acces to. Running your app as admin can help, but wont always help.

anyway, it wont get you any errors now.

Comment: i think there are some other fundamentals to creating an anti virus app.  would you like some training or mentoring with me?

Comment: It's working now, thank you so much! Is there a place where I can contact you if I encounter another problem?

Comment: your old code tried to acces files that you dont have permissions for. most files will work, but at some point you will always get stuck on acces error. but this explains why it seemed to work at first. the reason .toarray didnt work is because it has to finnish finding all files before the array is returned for you to process. it is never recommended to do that. when looping trough big  collections of files always loop trough them while enumerate dirrctories is locatig them on the disk.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is occasionally a necessary evil in porting old code, and a horrible idea in anything new.